# How to Fix List Index out of Range

Tags: python, list, indexing

My problem seems to lie in the line b=l[j] resulting in Type Error.
My program is to switch the last half and first half of a list.

I have already switched variables to fix the Problem.

The results should be include switching of the first and second half of the lists. Type Error Fix in line`[enter code here][1]`enter code here`e b=l[i].
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWutC.png)

Comment: PLEASE read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't clearly mentioned what you want to do.
But if you are trying to switch the first and the last halves of a list.Then you can do something like this-

```
switched_list = l[int(len(l)/2):] + l[0:int(len(l)/2)]
```

here, l is the list whose halves you want to swap.

You may face problem when list contains odd number of elements as these two halves will have unequal number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any error in the program. The logic, however, is flawed, specifically with:  `del l[i]` 
Here's the fixed code:

```
n= int(input("Enter limit:\n"))
l= []

for i in range(1,n+1):
    a = int(input("enter element: \n"))
    l.append(a)

print("the original list is: ", l)

list_half = int(len(l)/2)

fh = l[:list_half] #first half of the list
sh = l[list_half:]  #second half of the  list

new_list = sh + fh

print("new list is: ", new_list)
```

Edit: The answer by Harsh Agarwal eliminates the need of the two lists fh and sh. I included the two lists for better understanding.